# How to list folders in python that contain certain file types

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm incredibly new to python and am trying to learn it for my work search.  I'm looking at what I can automate on my computer and right now I have a lot of photos, videos, etc of my family, kids, etc that are all over the place on my network drive and I want to organize that.  What I'd ideally like to do is have a script that either hard codes or asks for a list of file types to look for, preferably ask the user as I would intend on using this for multiple different file types.  When done the script lists the folder(s) that contains those files and then moves on to moving the folder to the new location or just the files.  I've looked around on google searches but haven't found what I'm looking for.  Is this even possible in python?

Edit: Here's the original script I made. I hardcoded the jpg file type only as I didn't see how to do multiple file types.

```py
import glob, os, shutil

source_folder = input("Please enter the path and name of the folder you want"
                   " to move. (E.g: C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/myphotos):"
                   "\n")

files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_folder, "*.jpg"))
print(source_folder)

move_folder = input("Do you want to move the folder and its contents? (Y/N) ").lower()

print(move_folder)

dest_folder = input("Please enter the destination path (E.g: C:/Users/myusername/folder1):"
                    "\n")

if not os.path.exists(dest_folder): #create folder if it doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(dest_folder)

print(dest_folder)

if move_folder == "y":
    print("Ok. Moving folder now.")
    shutil.move(source_folder, dest_folder)
elif move_folder == "n":
        print("Ok. Only moving files in the folder")
for file in files:
   if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.move(file, dest_folder)
        print("Ok work complete")
```

Comment: And your question is?????

Comment: From what I know about glob, it doesn't allow for multiple extensions in one call. But you can just ask input of all extension types and have then space separated like `jpg git png` and then split that input with `input.split(' ')` and then iterate over that for the iglob and move the files in batches.

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcards for both file_name and file_type to move multiple file types

```
import glob, os, shutil

def _list_files(source_folder):
file_list = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
    for name in files:
        file_list.append(os.path.join(path, name))
    
count_dict = {}
for i in file_list:
    format_ = i.split(".")[-1]
    if format_ in count_dict.keys():
        count_dict[format_] += 1
    else:
        count_dict.update({format_:1})
print("\n\nDirectory and sub-directories contains:")
for key, value in count_dict.items():
    print(f"{value} {key} files.")

return file_list

def copy_files(file_list, source_folder, move_folder):
dest_folder = input("Please enter the destination path (E.g:C:/Users/myusername/folder1):""\n")
if not os.path.exists(dest_folder):
    os.makedirs(dest_folder)
if move_folder == 'y':
    shutil.move(source_folder, dest_folder)
    print("Move Completed!")
elif move_folder == 'n':
    file_types = input("Enter list of file types to copy \n or enter 'all' to copy all files \n Eg: ['jpeg', 'png', 'csv']")
    if isinstance(file_types, list):
        for i in file_types:
            for file in file_list:
                if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    shutil.move(file, dest_folder)
                    print("Move Completed!")
    elif isinstance(file_types, str) and file_types=='all':
        for file in file_list:
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                shutil.move(file, dest_folder)
                print("Move Completed!")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unable to determine file type")

source_folder = input("Please enter the path and name of the folder you want to move \n(E.g: C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/myphotos)")
source = _list_files(source_folder)

move_folder = input("Do you want to move the folder and its contents? (Y/N)").lower()
copy_files(source, source_folder, move_folder)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment.  Didn't get any notification that someone responded.  So this just moves all the files, which I don't want.  I just want to get a list of folders that contain specific files, like .jpg, .mp4, etc and then figure which one to move, whether it be the entire folder or just the specific file types in that folder.  I had this before where it listed all the files in the folders, but it was too long and creating a text file was hard to review as well.  I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Updated the logic to accept files types as an input and moves only them to the destination folder or otherwise all the files. Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I will take a look at it later today when I have more free time and I'll update you.